# Apple mail can't open links in Firefox because Classic environment is no longer supported

Tags: catalina, mail.app, error, firefox, url

I use Firefox as my default browser on macOS Catalina version 10.15.7.   Yesterday I used `brew` to upgrade Firefox to the latest version:

```
brew update
brew upgrade firefox
```

After the upgrade, Firefox works normally when I open it from applications menu.  It is the latest version: `91.0.1 (64-bit)`.

However since the upgrade, links in my mail through the Apple Mail app don't open.   When I click on them, nothing happens.  If I right click the link and select "open with" and choose Firefox, I get a dialog that says:

> You can't open the application "Firefox" because the Classic environment is no longer supported.

When I search for this error message, it appears to be related to application that are not compiled for macOS.  I shouldn't think that would apply to Firefox.

It appears that a second older version of Firefox 89.0.2 was still installed on my system in `/usr/local/Caskroom`.  I found it with the command `locate firefox` and then I removed it, but it didn't solve the problem.   `locate firefox` and `locate Firefox` now only show firefox installed in `/Applications/Firefox.app`

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

#### Update

This has something to do with `brew`.  I just tried installing Google Chome from brew because it also needed to up updated.  (Neither Firefox nor Chrome have the permissions needed to update themselves.)  I used the `-f` flag to force brew to overwrite the version of chrome that had been installed in some other way:

```
brew install google-chrome -f
```

After installing Chrome from brew, Mail can't open links in it either with the same message.   Is brew putting some wrapper around these applications that is using classic mode?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are not just installing Firefox using their point-and-click Firefox installer? https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

Comment: Why wouldn't I use a package manager?  I don't want to have to download and install software manually then have to continually repeat the process to keep it up to date.

Comment: Firefox (and many other apps) include self updating mechanisms so you don't have to do it manually - either choose fully automatic or choose just press a button when Firefox tells you there is a new version

Comment: Firefox 91 has tried to use different Apple systems calls and has messed up loading CSS bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1725436 Has this also broken other macOS integration. Report this to Mozilla as a bug. Firefox does not use standard Apple program APIs but is cross platform and uses lower level ones that do not do all a normal app does.

Comment: Does this still happen with later versions of Firefox - they removed the code that changed the macOS behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually downloading and installing Firefox and Chrome is a workaround for this problem.   It is only when they are installed by brew that there is a problem.  I'm not sure what the difference is when install via brew vs installed by the downloaded `.dmg`

The self updating mechanism mentioned in the comments doesn't work for me.   Firefox will tell me that an update is available and offer to download it, but when I click the download button, the dialog goes away and Firefox doesn't get updated.